# how to close the menu when clicked

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

const Navbar = () => {

    return (
      <div className="navbar-dark bg-dark shadow sticky-top">
        <div className="container">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand"><span className="effect">I <span className="rotation">Design</span> <span className="flash">Views</span></span>
              </Link>
              <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav m-auto p-3 mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/" className="nav-link active">Inicio</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/about" className="nav-link active">Bio</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/servicios" className="nav-link active">Servicios</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/contacto" className="nav-link active">Contacto</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

The previous versions of the bootstrap menu came by default to close the menu when clicking, now that I update I don't really know how to do it with react js, if anyone can help me I would appreciate it

Comment: Have you added the corresponding bootstrap `js` and `css` resources in the app? Because, I tried your code and it's working as expected by providing those resources.

Comment: "The previous versions of the bootstrap menu came by default to close the menu when clicking" .. what do you mean? close when clicking the menu toggler, OR close when clicking a menu item?

Comment: close when clicking menu item, my menu dont close when i click a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed out adding the `bootstrap's js` resource. Try adding the below in your `index.html`.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have used your code as it is, by just adding the `bootstrap js` resource it's working as expected. Below is the example,

```js
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
      <div className="navbar-dark bg-dark shadow sticky-top">
        <div className="container">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <a href="/" className="navbar-brand"><span className="effect">I <span className="rotation">Design</span> <span className="flash">Views</span></span>
              </a>
              <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav m-auto p-3 mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a href="/" className="nav-link active">Inicio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a href="/about" className="nav-link active">Bio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a href="/servicios" className="nav-link active">Servicios</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a href="/contacto" className="nav-link active">Contacto</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Note: Just for the demo purpose I have replaced `Link`s with `anchor`s.

Comment: My menu dont close if i put that script, open the links but dont close the menu. mi index is :                                                       
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();